# React Native update view outside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to update my render/view in react native from an event listener. The listener strictly has to be outside the view or component, is there a way to update render/view directly without using state/setstate. Right now it is being updated using the react hooks and is inside the component.

```
                         const App: () => React$Node = () => {                            
                          const [position, setposition] = useState({ 
                              lat: null,
                              lng: null,
                              foreground: false,
                              speed: null,
                              accuracy: null
                          });

                          useEffect(() => {    
                              Mylocationlistener.on('location', (result) => {
                                setposition({
                                  lat: result.location.latitude,
                                  lng: result.location.longitude,
                                  foreground: result.user.foreground,
                                  speed: result.location.speed,
                                  accuracy:result.location.accuracy
                                })
                                console.log('location listener:', stringify(result));
                              });
                              }, []);

                          return (
                            <>
                              <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
                              <SafeAreaView>
                                <ScrollView
                                  contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
                                  style={styles.scrollView}>
                                   <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                                      <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>My App{"\n"}</Text>
                                      <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Location Tracker</Text>
                                    </View>
                                  {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
                                    <View style={styles.engine}>
                                      <Text style={styles.footer}></Text>
                                    </View>
                                  )}
                                  <View style={styles.body}>
                                    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                                      <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Latitude: {position.lat}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                                      <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Longitude: {position.lng}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                                      <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Speed: {position.speed}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                                      <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Accuracy: {position.accuracy}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                  </View>
                                </ScrollView>
                              </SafeAreaView>
                            </>
                          );
                        };
```

Comment: Can i write an object outside the component to listen the listener updates and bind it with the view ? not sure if that will work.

Comment: Can you pass down the event in the component's props?

Comment: The event listener is an API, documentation clearly mentions to use it outside component and views. Props involves return view so not sure if that will work

Comment: You can define a function to fetch from your API, get the data, and then pass the data into your components via props, context, or local state. If you still can't do that, could you then provide a link to the documentation?

Comment: How can I write a function and return values from Mylocationlistener.on('location', (result) => {} in props and pass it into component ?

Comment: What does `Mylocationlistener` do? Is it trying to watch for url changes in the app? Post the documentation in your question please

Comment: Clearly, Mylocationlistener is looking for location updates for every few minutes. The whole idea is to use this listener without state/setstate to update the screen values with new lat/lng.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216603/discussion-between-gorp88-and-itsanewabstract).